# How can I write a LINQ query to get data dynamically based on user input

Tags: c#, angular, linq

So I have a frontend where a user can select a table where he wants to pull data from , along with a field that he wants to display on the frontend (image for reference below)[image]

How would I be able to actually pull the appropriate fields data from that table , These are all linked to a Template as shown above , and that Template is unique so no duplicate templates exist.

I tried doing some research on LINQ queries but I found that most of the relevant answers where on older versions of Entity Framework , so I tried to replicate the answers but I was unable to do so.

(edit) I must apologise for the lack of info given on this post , I actually am busy writing a dynamic LINQ query now where I query the table selected by the user on the frontend i.e. Bill Of entry , and then do a select on the fields selected by the user , but to answer the comments by most users my problem was understanding the logic and how to write the LINQ query to actually process what happens on the frontend , for example , how would I be able to tell my DB to extract the field TEstCOL from the Database with its data , or Debtor Field from DB with its data , using linq

Comment: It's not clear what your desired outcome is. Do you want the tables selected from the front-end, or the columns, or both? What have you tried already & why didn't it work?

Comment: From your screenshot and description it isn't clear what your goal is or where you're stuck. Please show some code that you have, and some code that you have tried but didn't work.

Comment: You need to use `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` library. There are over a million examples on Google, like this: https://code-maze.com/using-dynamic-linq/

Comment: so basically my question boils down to , am I going to have to write a linq query for each and every one of these lookup combinations , for example if a user selects table Bill_Of_Entry and field debtor , then that will have it's own LINQ Query and if a user select a different field like ToOrder , then that will also be a seperate LINQ query ?

Comment: A separate Linq query to do what?

Comment: As far as i can see, you are constructing a db query. So why not construct the SQL directly and not a Linq expression which will be translated into SQL?